# vue.js local images are not displayed on github page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, github-pages

In my project, I have a component named "link_button" and I am using v-for to create them. Each button contains a title and an icon, on local host the icons display correctly, but whenever I uploaded my project on github and open the static page via github page. The icons were not found by the server with the error saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()". I have tried many different methods to overcome this path problem but eventually none of them work out for me.

In my app.vue

```
<link_button
        v-for="(item, index) in get_button_array"
        :key="index"
        :title="item.name"
        :icon="item.icon"
 >
 </link_button>
```

and in computed I return an array like this

```
get_button_array() {
      const button_array = [
        {
          name: "會員",
          icon: require('@/assets/member.png')
        },
        {
          name: "優惠卷",
          icon: require('@/assets/coupon.png')
        },
        {
          name: "積點",
          icon: require('@/assets/point.png')
        },
        {
          name: "問卷",
          icon: require('@/assets/form.png')
        },
        {
          name: "集點卡",
          icon: require('@/assets/card.png')
        },
        {
          name: "抽獎",
          icon: require('@/assets/lottery.png')
        },
        {
          name: "寄存卡",
          icon: require('@/assets/storage.png')
        },
        {
          name: "行銷活動",
          icon: require('@/assets/event.png')
        },
        {
          name: "儲值信託",
          icon: require('@/assets/deposit.png')
        },
        {
          name: "履約票卷",
          icon: require('@/assets/ticket.png')
        },
      ]

      return button_array;
    }
```

and for my button component

```
<template>
  <div class="link_button button_notLogin" v-if="!loginState">
    <img :src="icons[button_index]" class="link_button_icon" />
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="link_button" v-else>
    <img :src="icon" class="link_button_icon" />
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

Comment: repo or url website?

Comment: repo, but I fixed it. The image file size is causing the problem,.